# Oracle SQL: Find and remove duplicates (same value in different columns)

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, ora-00933

Oracle SQL: How to find and remove duplicates

I have only read-only access to Oracle (Can use SELECT command only).

**Logic:** Two users 'A' & 'B' are having same Company Name & First Name

**Columns to extract:**

```
ID of A
ID of B
Company Name of A
Company Name of B
First Name of A
First Name of B
```

**I am using below query:**

```
select a.id, b.id, a.name, b.name, a.company, b.company from
(select id, company, name where country = 'USA') a,
(select id, company, name where country = 'UK') b
where a.id <> b.id
and lower(a.company) = lower(b.company)
and a.username = b.username
```

---

Here I am getting each row two times (refer the below table):

A_ID    ..........  B_ID    ..........  A_NAME  ..........  B_NAME  ..........  A_COMPANY   ..........  B_COMPANY

3592382 ....    1977967 ....    Peter   ................    Peter   .................   A.B.C.  .....................   A.B.C.

1977967 ....    3592382 ....    Peter   ................    Peter   .................   A.B.C.  .....................   A.B.C.

5949363 ....    5941818 ....    Joseph  ............    Joseph  ..............  X.Y.Z.  .....................   X.Y.Z.

5941818 ....    5949363 ....    Joseph  ............    Joseph  ..............  X.Y.Z.  .....................   X.Y.Z.

Comment: The others have mentioned a few things wrong with your syntax but I see a more fundamental issue.  Why would American and British companies be considered duplicates when they have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues with the query.

1) If you do `select val1,val2 from a, b` ,you would get a `cross-join` result.

2) The aliased tables don't have a `from` clause.

You say you only have `select` access. Hence you can only `select` the non-duplicate values.

```
select distinct a.id, b.id, a.name, b.name, a.company, b.company 
from
(select id, company, name from tablename where country = 'USA') a
join
(select id, company, name from tablename where country = 'UK') b
on a.id = b.id and lower(a.company) = lower(b.company) and a.username = b.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot tablenames in subqueries. Also I recommend not to get a.col and b.col when both values will be the same (That's the condition), as it reduce performance and doesn't add any valuable data

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, a.name, a.company
FROM tablename a
JOIN tablename b
    ON (a.name == b.name AND a.company == b.company AND a.username == b.username)
WHERE a.country = 'USA'
    AND b.country = 'UK'
```